# Pyang support for Yang 1.1

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

In our Application we use Pyang (pyang 1.7.3) for our Yang support. As of today our Application is complaint to RFC 6020, Yang 1.0. We would like to upgrade our Application to Support Yang 1.1, RFC7950. Any idea is Pyang 1.7.3 compatible with Yang 1.1? What is the stable release of Pyang wrt Yang 1.1 support?

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite some time since I actively tracked pyang progress, but at that time it had most of 1.1 implemented - with the exception of the new definition contribution mechanism between modules and submodules. The new mechanism requires top-level definitions and the schema tree defined in any of the submodules or the module itself to be accessible in an arbitrary submodule or the module itself, even if not explicitly included.

It was decided that 1.1 would not be supported by the DSDL plugin - if you rely on pyang for instance document validation, that may pose a problem. Reason was that the implementation would require extending XSLT processors to support new XPath functions, hindering portability of the implementation.

I don't see anything in the [change log](https://github.com/mbj4668/pyang) suggesting those issues were resolved.

Comment: Thanks @predi, can you also comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56741430/yang-action-vs-rpc-and-anydata-vs-anyxml

Comment: Thanks @predi, regarding pyang support for Yang 1.1 we use it mostly for converting Yang to Yin. So any idea if (pyang 1.7.3) is stable wrt this aspect?

Comment: @Ram, not sure about that. YIN/YANG conversion is one of the simpler implementation challenges RFC7950 has to offer, so I doubt stability would be an issue. Besides, pyang is open source - if it doesn't work, fix it. :)