# Netconf Notifications

Tags: rfc, ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-netconf

RFC 5277 defines notification replay support. Just wondering what customer problems this notification replay can solve? What could be the need to scan through list of past notifications? At any point of time, controllers can always fire "get" RPC and determine current state.

Any inputs on this are appreciated.

Comment: *At any point of time, controllers can always fire RPC and determine current state.* Which RPC? :)

Comment: I've seen systems that capture, store, and display information from the managed network, such as alarms or warnings. Notification replay simply makes it easier to receive missing notifications, if the connection between a client and server(s) is severed for any reason. To an operator it may be important to receive the alarms lost in limbo during the "blackout", and to an implementer, it makes it easier for the implementation to just resume business as usual, when the connection is restored.

Comment: Thanks @predi, by RPC I meant 'get' RPC. I had mentioned that in my question, looks like since I mentioned it as an empty XML tag, the same is not shown in my question in the display.

Comment: Hi @predi, do you have any idea on this issue https://github.com/mbj4668/pyang/issues/500 ?

Answer (score 0):

Notification replay is mostly required to sync NETCONF clients with servers without the need to do a full  RPC.
In some systems, the configuration + operational data becomes quite large, so the notification replay allows for a delta sync.

The main problem with this is that the server will only keep a limited time window of notifications; so if a client asks for a replay of the last week, the server may be only able to provide a subset of that.

RESTCONF has a different solution for this same issue, the last-modified header field(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8040#section-3.4.1.1), which allows for doing a get of 'data that has changed since timestamp x'.